# Python 3.6 - Read encoded text from file and convert to string

Tags: python, python-3.x, encoding, decoding, python-3.6

Hopefully someone can help me out with the following. It is probably not too complicated but I haven't been able to figure it out. My "output.txt" file is created with:

```
f = open('output.txt', 'w')
print(tweet['text'].encode('utf-8'))
print(tweet['created_at'][0:19].encode('utf-8'))
print(tweet['user']['name'].encode('utf-8')) 
f.close()
```

If I don't encode it for writing to file, it will give me errors. So "output" contains 3 rows of utf-8 encoded output:

```
b'testtesttest'
b'line2test'
b'\xca\x83\xc9\x94n ke\xc9\xaan'
```

In "main.py", I am trying to convert this back to a string:

```
f = open("output.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8")
text = f.read()
print(text)
f.close()
```

Unfortunately, the b'' - format is still not removed. Do I still need to decode it? If possible, I would like to keep the 3 row structure.
My apologies for the newbie question, this is my first one on SO :)

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Uh, does it literally have `b'testtesttest'` in the file?

Comment: [literal_eval](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) could help you if the `b` and `'` are in the file

Comment: hm, can you use `f.write` instead of `print`?

Comment: @MaxChrétien, that seems to work! :) Thank you!

Comment: `f = open('output.txt', 'wb')` try to add a `b` then, it will allow you to write `bytes` to the file instead of `str`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the help of the people answering my question, I have been able to get it to work. The solution is to change the way how to write to file:

```
     tweet = json.loads(data)
     tweet_text = tweet['text'] #  content of the tweet
     tweet_created_at = tweet['created_at'][0:19] #  tweet created at
     tweet_user = tweet['user']['name']  # tweet created by
     with open('output.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
           f.write(tweet_text + '\n')
           f.write(tweet_created_at+ '\n')
           f.write(tweet_user+ '\n')
```

Then read it like:

```
    f = open("output.txt", "r", encoding='utf-8')
    tweettext = f.read()
    print(text)
    f.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of specifying the encoding when opening the file, use it to decode as you read.

```
f = open("output.txt", "rb")
text = f.read().decode(encoding="utf-8")
print(text)
f.close()
```

Comment: this results in the following error: 
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'

Comment: @Hoenie the only way to get byte strings (`b'abc'`) is by opening the file for reading in binary `"rb"`, if you are not reading bytes from the file how are you ending up with bytestrings?

Comment: the "rb" and decoding gives me actually the same output "r" and without decoding

Answer (score 0):

If `b` and the quote `'` are in your file, that means this in a problem with your file. Someone probably did `write(print(line))` instead of `write(line)`. Now to decode it, you can use [`literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval). Otherwise @m_callens answer's should be ok.

```
import ast

with open("b.txt", "r") as f:
    text = [ast.literal_eval(line) for line in f]

for l in text: 
    print(l.decode('utf-8'))

# testtesttest
# line2test
# ʃɔn keɪn
```

Comment: Actually, I write it to file myself. I encode it to utf-8 for the text file otherwise I get a errors, this is from a Twitter stream. The printing is done with the following code: print(tweet['text'].encode('utf-8'))

Comment: :) Please edit your question as how you create the file in the first place. Also, have you tried my code yet?

Comment: understood, I edited my question. I tried your code but the output stays the same. thanks for your feedback!

Comment: Edit my question, sorry I didn't try with python 3.X before... should work now but I'm working on something better

Comment: Your comment "write(print(line)) instead of write(line)" was spot on, I will rewrite my code. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Don't hesitate to post your own code as an anwser when it is good enough, this problem happens to a lot of ppl actualy, anyway, glad I could help :)